# Associative array decoding in JSON

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am trying to change the class of a list of elements based on information in a DB. I figure the easy way was via an array. I build the array on the php side as follows.

```
 $setClassResult = array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
 {
 $setClassResult= array_push_assoc($setClassResult, $row['item_id'], $row['parent']);
 }  
 echo json_encode(array($setClassResult));
 break;
```

which give me....

```
 [{"830":"0","734":"830","733":"830","732":"830","735":"830","737":"830","736":"830","738":"830","739":"830","740":"830","741":"830","742":"830","872":"0","869":"872","868":"872","880":"872","964":"872"}]
```

to decode and change the elements I use.....

```
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        $("#recordsArray_"+key).toggleClass(val);   
        alert(key+" "+val);
  });
```

The alert happens once with `0[object,Object]` Is this because of the way I created the array? The first thing I notice wrong is the `[` and `]` around the JSON.

Comment: Instead of `array_push_assoc`, do you just want to `$setClassResult[$row['item_id']] = $row['parent']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to add extra array, try with :

```
echo json_encode($setClassResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your result is in array of object format:

```
 [{"830":"0","734":"830","733":"830","732":"830","735":"830","737":"830","736":"830","738":"830","739":"830","740":"830","741":"830","742":"830","872":"0","869":"872","868":"872","880":"872","964":"872"}]
```

So when you iterate, it iterates through array first & says key is 0 & value is an object.so, if you later iterate through value which is an object, you will get it

or as soju if u dont require to store it in array of objects but a single object & iterate once.